# extract code from cgal

Tags: cgal

I would like to use the halfedge data structure of CGAL in my project.

Since it is licenced by LGPL, I would prefer to distribute this small piece together with my software, instead of requiring the installation of this big library on the user's system.

So my question is, is there something like boost's bcp for Cgal? I started to manually copy the halfedge source files but it looks fairly compicated.

thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think so. Easiest would be to compile an example with g++ -E and grep through the output to get the list of headers included, though many may not be really needed.

Comment: Note that unless you modify the code, you will need to link with libCGAL in debug mode...

Comment: thank you for the info! 
Can you explain how to modify the code to avoid this dependancy?

Comment: Don't use debug mode (CGAL_NDEBUG) or redefine CGAL_assertion and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no automated way to extract only a subset of CGAL headers or just a package including its dependencies. You can try to do this manually though by just following all include dependencies.

Even if you do this, the biggest problem is that CGAL assertions require linking to `libCGAL`. You can avoid this by disabling the assertions through the `CGAL_NDEBUG` macro. It's also not easy to see from a CGAL distribution if a package compiles code into `libCGAL`, but neither `Polyhedron` nor `Halfedge_DS` do that, so you should be fine.